# Center of mass & Big Bang Theory

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion, big-bang

I have read in my text books about the Big Bang theory and quote "***the entire matter in the universe was once concentrated in a single very dense and hot fire ball; it exploded some 20 billion years ago***."
My question is this: if we applied the concept of center of mass to the big bang, what would be the situation?

Comment: Related : [Did the big bang happen at a point?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)

Comment: Can you give us the name(s) of the author(s) of that "textbook"? It's time to send him/her/them a lemon, because he/she/they is/are talking utter nonsense. That's not a home schooling "textbook", by any chance, is it?

Comment: 20 billion years ago? You have a book from the future!

Comment: I find it difficult to believe physics textbooks anywhere in the world do contain the nonsense you are quoting. I hope you are not going to convince us such is the case in India?